# Upload to azure blob fails with exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, specflow, azure-iot-hub

I tried uploading file as below

```
public async Task UploadFiles(string instanceType, string transportType, int numberOfFiles)
        {
            var instance = FeatureTestContext.Instances[instanceType];
            var registeredType = GetTypeDefinition(instance.GetTypeId());
            var objectId = instance.GetId();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
            {
                var file = new FileInfo($"{objectId}-{i}-{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}.txt");
                var storagePath = $"UAT/Robotics/{instanceType}";
                File.WriteAllLines(file.FullName, new string[] { instance.AsJson(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToString()});

                if (transportType.Equals("gateway", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var response = await DataAccessService.UploadFileAsync(objectId, instance.GetModel(), file, storagePath);
                    Assert.IsTrue(response, "Expected the file to be uploaded");
                }
                else if (transportType.Equals("edge", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //rest to the edge module ID since this is what will be used when the edge module uploads the file.
                    objectId = Guid.Parse(_fixture.RoboticsEdgeModuleId);

                    Assert.Fail("Uploading files from the edge causes Edge to fail");
                    var response = await DataAccessService.SendFileUploadCommandAsync(
                            _fixture.RoboticsEdgeModuleId, 
                            file.Name,
                            File.ReadAllText(file.FullName),
                            "abb.ability.device");

                    Assert.IsTrue(response, "Exepcted to be able to send the uploadFile command");
                }
                else
                {
                    await DataAccessService.UploadFileThroughIoTHub(objectId, file, Client.TransportType.Amqp);
                }

                var fileUpload = new FileUpload();
                fileUpload.File = file;
                fileUpload.ObjectId = objectId;
                fileUpload.Model = instance.GetModel();
                fileUpload.StoragePath = storagePath;
                ScenarioTestContext.FileUploads.Add(fileUpload);
            }
        }
```

Then the below method is called from else condition as in above method

```
public async Task UploadFileThroughIoTHub(Guid objectId, FileInfo file, TransportType transportType)
        {
            var deviceClient = _provisioningService.CreateDeviceClient(transportType);

            using (var sourceData = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await deviceClient.UploadToBlobAsync($"{objectId}/{file.Name}", sourceData);
            }
        }
```

The code to create device client as below

```
public Client.DeviceClient CreateDeviceClient(Client.TransportType transportType)
        {
            if (_fixture.DeviceName == null && _deviceKey == null) return null;


            if (_client == null)
            {
                if (_fixture.UseCertificate)
                {
                    var initialPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), PathCertPath.ToString());
                    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(initialPath);
                    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*");
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(initialPath, filesInDir[0].ToString())),
                     "123",
                     X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);
                    var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithX509Certificate(Path.GetFileName(filesInDir[0].ToString().Replace(".pfx", "")), cert);
                    _client = DeviceClient.Create(_fixture.IoTHubHostName, auth, transportType);
                }
                else if (!_fixture.UseCertificate)
                {
                    _client = Client.DeviceClient.Create(_fixture.IoTHubHostName,
                         new Client.DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(_fixture.DeviceName, _deviceKey),
                         transportType);
                }

            }
            return _client;
        }
```

While debugging one of the **sourceData** property from '**UploadFileThroughIoTHub**' method comes as below

*'sourceData.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'*

The stack trace was as below. The test is run using Specflow.

**Message:**
    *Test method RoboticsRegressionTests.Feature.RoboticsRegressionFeature.PublishFile_ABTesting_IoTHub threw exception:*
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Stack Trace:**
    *IAuthorizationProvider.GetPasswordAsync()
    HttpClientHelper.ExecuteAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, Uri requestUri, Func`3 modifyRequestMessageAsync, Func`2 isSuccessful, Func`3 processResponseMessageAsync, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpClientHelper.PostAsync[T1,T2](Uri requestUri, T1 entity, IDictionary`2 errorMappingOverrides, IDictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpTransportHandler.UploadToBlobAsync(String blobName, Stream source)
    DataAccessService.UploadFileThroughIoTHub(Guid objectId, FileInfo file, TransportType transportType) line 592
    RoboticsRegressionStepDefinition.UploadFiles(String instanceType, String transportType, Int32 numberOfFiles) line 873
    <b__0>d.MoveNext() line 32
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    <b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop() line 125
    AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) line 72
    BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) line 49
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments) line 395
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 316
    TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep() line 132
    RoboticsRegressionFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
    RoboticsRegressionFeature.PublishFile(String testcaseName, String instanceType, String transportType, String numberOfTimes, String[] exampleTags) line 179
    RoboticsRegressionFeature.PublishFile_ABTesting_IoTHub()*

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting the following issue reported here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/259

Please check the .NET version you are using or see if the workaround specified at
**"labiraus commented on Dec 23, 2017"** on the above link can help your case as well.

hth

Comment: Looks similar. Need to analyse and confirm.